Add functionality to ajax_add_to_cart button in woocommerce to close a custom modal after item was added to cart
Im trying to close a modal with javascript (doesnt matter if its with js or jquery or php), I've tried adding custom JS with a button pointer like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
   $('.btn[data-product_id='11068651']').click( function(){
      document.querySelector(".speak-up-modal").style.display = "none";
   });
   $('.btn[data-product_id='11068652']').click( function(){
      document.querySelector(".speak-up-modal").style.display = "none";
   });
})(jQuery);
</script>

And add this to the wp_footer this way:
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'single_add_to_cart_event_button_function' );
function single_add_to_cart_event_button_function() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $('.btn[data-product_id='11068651']').click( function(){
                    document.querySelector(".speak-up-modal").style.display = "none";
                });
                $('.btn[data-product_id='11068652']').click( function(){
                    document.querySelector(".speak-up-modal").style.display = "none";
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}

But nothing works, this is how Im using the woocommerce buttons in the modal:
<a href="#" class="button add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart btn" data-product_id="11068652" data-quantity="1" rel="nofollow">

And nothing I do adds the event to the button, any chance for some help in modifying/adding functionality to this button?
This is what I've tried:
Button:
<a href="#" class="button add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart btn" data-product_id="11068652" data-quantity="1" rel="nofollow">

Inside the JS in footer itself where I initiate the modal
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
   $('.btn[data-product_id='11068651']').click( function(){
      document.querySelector(".speak-up-modal").style.display = "none";
   });
   $('.btn[data-product_id='11068652']').click( function(){
      document.querySelector(".speak-up-modal").style.display = "none";
   });
})(jQuery);
</script>

And in functions.php:
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'single_add_to_cart_event_button_function' );
function single_add_to_cart_event_button_function() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $('.btn[data-product_id='11068651']').click( function(){
                    document.querySelector(".speak-up-modal").style.display = "none";
                });
                $('.btn[data-product_id='11068652']').click( function(){
                    document.querySelector(".speak-up-modal").style.display = "none";
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}

Heres a staging env to check it out: https://wordpress-997383-4781804.cloudwaysapps.com/product/speak-up-digital/
Only in console the JS/jQuery code above works...

To close a modal this is tempting but wrong because modal affects the entire page :
document.querySelector(".speak-up-modal").style.display = "none";

Instead use the classic :
$(".speak-up-modal").modal('hide');


Does nothing, the problem isnt with showing\hiding the modal, the problem is adding and event listener to a button that has some functions bound to it and nothing You try to add to its functionality works, thanks anyway! :)

So for some strange reason, due to caching in the server, this whole time the code snippet from above wasnt loading into my staging website.
All I had to do is refresh cache and basically after that I could see the code and everything worked just fine!
Thanks everybody!
